# How to do a SwiftUI "step by step" Animation?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI animation and struggle to find what I'm looking for.

I coded a slider connected to a `@State var mu: Double`, causing multiple `Circle()` to change their `.frame()` size (according to a mathematical model).

[image: With slider]

I would like to turn this into an animation, so I created a button that changes the `mu` value `withAnimation`.

The result is not what I'm looking for :

[image: Animation]

SwiftUI smartly transitions between the starting and ending sizes of the `Circles()`, instead of actualy "sliding" the value as I want, and showing all the "in-between" magic.

What approach should I take ? (I really struggle to find keywords to search)

Comment: How did you generate that circle distribution?

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI is pretty good at choosing the intermediary animation of certain objects, but for more complex objects you'll have to define explicitly what is being animated.

For that you need to manually define the `animatableData` property of your struct/class which lets you specify which values are to be changed for the animation.

Without seeing your code it's impossible to help further, but Paul Hudson has a good example of `animatableData`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/animating-complex-shapes-with-animatablepair

You can also search for the Type `AnimatablePair`